# Java - Calling void methods and storing their value

Tags: java

This is a  question from a past exam paper. The question asks to declare a variable `c` of type `Counter` in a new class. I should then intialise it to a new instance of `Counter` with `n` taking a value of 100. I must then increment its `n` field twice. Then print the value of the `n` field to `System.out`.

I have done both classes, but i am not sure about the `Counter2` class. I think i may be declaring the `Counter` variable wrong.

```
public class Counter {
    private int n;
    public int x;

    public Counter(int theN){
        this.n=theN;
    }

    public int getN(){
        return n;
    }

    public void inc(){
        x = 1+ getN();
    }
}

public class Counter2{
    Counter c;

    public int incrementTwice(){
        int i = 0;

        while(i<2){
            c.inc();
            i++;
        }
        return c.x;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        c = new Counter(100);
        int finalResult = c.getN();
        System.out.println(finalResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nambari, just tried static but it just prints 100. Guessing there is something wrong with my while loop

Comment: Counter c = new Counter(100);

Comment: I don't understand the question (and the title even less). In `Counter2` you'd need to actually *instantiate* a `Counter` in order to do anything useful with it, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to increment the `n` field (100) twice. And then print the `n` field. So the aim is to get 102.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `inc()` you are not actually incrementing `n`. You are setting `x` to `n+1`.

So, it does not matter how many times you run `inc`, before the first run you will have `n = initial Value` and `x=0`, after the first run and following you have `n = initialValue` and `x = n + 1`

Comment: the first part of the question asked me to create a public method `inc` that adds 1 to `n` and returns no result. So i'm guessing i have to use this method to increment 100 to 102.

Comment: That is not what you `inc` is doing.

Comment: Yeah thanks i changed the `inc()` method to `n = 1+ getN();`. Made a few tweaks and it works now

Comment: @nsc010 - `inc()` method would be best as simply `n += 1` or `n = n + 1` or even `n++`; there's no need to call `getN()` since you're within the `Counter` class already.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, yeah thanks for that, that makes sense. I have modified my code now.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    c = new Counter(100);

    int finalResult = c.getN();
    System.out.println(finalResult);
}
```

I would expect the output to be `100`

The call stack would be the following:

```
1) Set c.N = 100;  
2) set finalResult = c.X (100)  
3) Print finalResult (100)
```

You never make a call to `incrementTwice`.  Your main should be the following:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Counter2 counter2 = new Counter2();  
    counter2.c.n = 100;  
    counter2.incrementTwice();
    int finalResult = counter2.c.getN();
    System.out.println(finalResult);
}
```

The key is that in `inc()` you are adding to `x` and not adding to `n` so you need to return `x`

Answer (score 1):

- Why have a while loop? Why not just increment it in two lines. That would be clearer in my opinion
- Personally I wouldn't use getN() in your inc method. This is a public interface to the class. I would access the n variable directly eg  x = 1 + n;
- You dont need x and n. Just increment n. This could be causing the problem as you are always incrementing a value (n) that is never changing. You need to reassign to n if you want to increment twice.

I would do just

```
n+=2
```

to add two to n

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `n` is the value of the counter, "declare a variable c of type Counter" and "initialize it to a new instance... taking a value of 100" would be accomplished like this: `Counter c = new Counter(100);`. Incrementing its value twice would be as simple as this:

```
int value = c.getValue(); 
value++;
value++;
c.setValue(value);
```

... assuming that `getValue()` is defined as the method that gets the Counter's variable.

So putting it all together is as simple as this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Counter c;

    public MyClass() {
        c = new Counter(100);
    }

    public void increment() {
        int value = c.getValue();
        value++;
        c.setValue(value);
    }

    public void printCounterValue() {
        System.out.println(c.getValue());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass(); // creates new class with Counter c initialized to 100
        instance.increment(); // increment once
        instance.increment(); // increment twice
        instance.printCounterValue(); // print to screen
    }
}
```

Of course this could be simplified further -- incrementing could be as simple as creating a method in the `Counter` class called `increment()` which simply does `n++`, for example -- but this is a basic implementation of the solution.

(Implementing the `increment()` in Counter would look something like this:)

```
public void increment() {
    n++; // equivalent to n = n+1 or n+= 1
}
```